# Are there enough curves (to connect 'points' of f.g. algebras)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

(Intuition: any two points in a connected space may be connected by a path. I would like to know if something like this holds in certain category of `connected algebraic spaces'. I formulate the precise question in terms of commutative algebra.)

Let ${\cal A}$ be the category of finitely generated (associative unital) commutative ${\mathbb{C}}$-algebras with exactly two idempotents.

Let ${f, g : A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}}$ be two maps in ${\cal A}$.

Does it exist a map ${c : A \rightarrow C}$ (always in ${\cal A}$) with $C$ a curve such that both $f$ and $g$ factor through $c$? (I.e. such that there are maps ${f', g' : C \rightarrow \mathbb{C}}$ such that ${f' c = f}$ and ${g' c = g}$.)

Here by "curve" I mean a connected finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of Krull dimension 1.

Comment: How do you map an algebra to a curve?

Comment: Curve := finitely generated algebra of Krull dimension $1$ ? Also, are your algebras automatically commutative?

Comment: Related: rationally connected varieties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_variety#Rationally_connected_variety

Comment: Apologies for the mixed terminology. Krull dimension 1, everything is commutative.

Comment: To clarify: "exactly two idempotents" means that 0 and 1 are the only idempotents (and they are distinct), and this condition is the same as "connected", right?

Comment: @TimCampion : Yes.

Comment: The answer is yes. I would suggest you to check how to do this when $A$ is a domain and tweak it for more general rings.

Comment: @Mohan: I don't see it. If it is a standard fact, I would be grateful for a reference.

Comment: Any two points of an irreducible variety can be connected by an irreducible curve. A beautiful proof was given by C. P. Ramanujam and can be found in his collected works. If dimension of $X$ s one, there is nothing to prove. If dimension is larger, blow up the two points and by Bertini, a general hyperplane intersects it in an irreducible variety. Since the exceptional divisors are codimension one, this variety intersects both and thus its image in $X$ is an irreducible variety passing through both points and one less dimension.

Comment: The previous comment certainly adds something useful.
Yet, I find the situation somewhat unsatisfactory.
The original post is a very basic statement involving a couple of maximal ideals and the existence of a not-quite-maximal ideal relating the previous couple.
@Mohan's comment indicates that a closely related question (involving a couple of points in a variety) has a positive answer thanks to an ingenious application (due to Ramanujan) of Bertini's Theorem. 
Isn't there an alternative, direct, and purely commutative-algebraic proof of the original question?